# Redirecting PathPrefixRoutes in WebApp2

Tags: webapp2

I'd like to redirect a series of established routes in WebApp2 that are under a PathPrefixRoute. Something like /foo/bar and foo/baz would be redirected to newfoo/bar and newfoo/baz, for instance.

Here's what I would have today:

```
import webapp2
from webapp2_extras import routes
....
routes.PathPrefixRoute('/foo', [
    webapp2.Route('/bar', 'BarHandler', name='bar_handler'),
    webapp2.Route('/baz', 'BazHandler', name='baz_handler'),
    # Many more routes below this.
])
....
```

I'd like to end up with

```
import webapp2
from webapp2_extras import routes
....
routes.PathPrefixRoute('/newfoo', [
    webapp2.Route('/bar', 'BarHandler', name='bar_handler'),
    webapp2.Route('/baz', 'BazHandler', name='baz_handler'),
    # Many more routes below this.
]),
....
```

while making sure that people who visit the old urls are properly redirected to the new ones.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could just set up a catch all for `/foo/some_arg` in your main app

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
  ('/foo/(\w+)', OldFooHandler),
    ...
```

And then have a class that redirects any request for the old handler to the new one

```
class OldFooHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self, second_arg):
    self.redirect('/newfoo/%s' % second_arg)
```

And of course you just use your route handler to catch everything else passed to `/newfoo`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm hoping there's a way to do it without adding additional handlers. Similar to webapp2.RedirectHandler's use in a single route, but that essentially says "this prefix redirects to that prefix with everything after it still attached.